# Homework Prolog Help: =:=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, predicate, rule, instantiation-error

I don't want to have to post the whole homework assignment and all my code online, so I'll just put where the specific problems takes place. I can add and explain more if necessary.

But essentially, I write my code and then it gets tested by my professors code. My code logically works according to his instructions. In this specific snipett of my code, I'm supposed to check if its a valid move. In the first and last parameter, the list represents [missionary, cannibal, whether near of far from shore]. My code works and passes all tests, except when my professor passes in `_` as for M1 and M2.

My Code

```
move([M1,_,L1],onemissionary,[M2,_,L2]) :-
    L1 == near, L2 == far, M1 =:= M2+1;
    L1 == far, L2 == near, M2 =:= M1+1.
```

His code that calls my code and causes the error.

```
move([_,2,near],onemissionary,[_,1,far]).
```

The error:

```
=:=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

So I understand that it is crashing because my teacher's test code is throwing in a `_` for `M1`and `M2` thus it errors trying to perform `_ =:= _ + 1`. However, I can't change his test code, so how could I change my code so that instead of having an error, it returns a fail?

Comment: Since I guess M1 and M2 are integers, you could use #= instead of =:= to work with domains instead of.
  
At least the test case you provided us with will work with #=.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, sorry I'm new to prolog. Are you suggesting my code should be `move([M1,_,L1],onemissionary,[M2,_,L2]) :-
    L1 == near, L2 == far, M1 #= M2+1;
    L1 == far, L2 == near, M2 #= M1+1.` ? Because that doesn't work

Comment: @byurocks23 The `#=` operator is provided by the [CLPFD](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) library. Unlike the other operators, it isn't built-in.

Comment: @byurocks23 *...because that doesn't work* isn't enough information to enable anyone to help. Either you need to use `CLP(FD)` or otherwise refactor your code. `=:=/2` expects its arguments to be totally ground (have no variables that are unassigned).